# JSON columns from df

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have data in df column as a string. I want to convert that into JSON format. I am using df['data'].to_json('data.json') to convert, after that I am getting it as below:

```
"0":"{\"business_card\": {\"alternate_mobile_no\": \"1234567890\", \"business_name\": \"Alock \/ FATHER'S Home Business \", \"coordinates\": {\"lat\": 31.1108119, \"lng\": 72.80649559999999}, \"location\": \"Street 1, FSD, Isl\", \"mobile_no\": \"123456789\", \"name\": \"Aloc Meh \"}, \"business_name\": \"Aloc \/ FATHER'S Home Business \", \"businesss_type\": \"General Store\", \"cashbook_current_balance\": -80, \"contextID\": \"d035dbe3-cee3-4e59-b964-4899b7d63a4d\", \"current_location\": {\"latitude\": 31.1062476, \"longitude\": 72.7949253}, \"fcm_token\": \"eNgv3-itRlm4FZZ901FtmY:APA91bG_HZObrNXbJJkn7ILDLlkLctTxW4eUHFxOILL42BX9Xb_uWxk5RXdHeSCNg7RXhf3drLAeVDIH4lqfOOwmUQz_8oprvPssvB0KiPXGPw7yDGww6hyOGJpQDyZFWimFc3lVCZNl\", \"fromNewAPP\": true, \"id\": \"DrcOaVjp8FWTic6okQAYx2quxrU2\", \"img_base_64\": \"\", \"img_url\": \"\", \"is_active\": true, \"location_our_logs\": null, \"location_past_logs\": null, \"nameLowerCase\": \"ishtiaq mehmood \", \"rating\": {\"feedback\": \"\", \"rated_timestamp\": {\"_seconds\": 1612024976, \"_nanoseconds\": 766000000}, \"stars\": 4}, \"referral_code\": \"DrcOaVjp\", \"user_last_activity\": {\"_seconds\": 1633051286, \"_nanoseconds\": 907000000}, \"user_signup_date\": {\"_seconds\": 1598745600, \"_nanoseconds\": 0}}",
```

I want this to be without '' escape character. Secondly, my columns are not being specified as columns in the .JSON file. Like "business_card" is not specified as column rather it is just a string value. Kindly, suggest a solution.

Comment: `Like "business_card" is not specified as column rather it is just a string value.` What does this mean?

Comment: From your question, which is kind of hard to understand, it seems like you might need to do `import json; df['data'].apply(json.loads)`. Please post a [mcve] , otherwise its impossible to help you

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to reproduce your example, but it seems `df['data'].to_json('data.json')` returns a json string. You could try to convert it to dict like this:

```
import json

out = json.loads(your_json_string)
df  = pd.DataFrame(out)
```